# Finding an $a$, such that $\forall x(x^x-(a\cdot x)!=0).$

Tags: limits, recreational-mathematics

My previous question was wrongly formulated, I wanted to know the value of $a$ as $x$ gets bigger, but due to my limited math knowledge I can't solve it.
So, is $a$ a constant and what would its value be?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> *So, is **a** a constant ?*

No. The [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) or [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) cannot be expressed in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), which is what would happen if such an ***a*** were to exist.